# Idiomatic way to fetch the first occurrence of a specific constructor from a list

Tags: haskell

Is there a nice way to find the first occurrence of a constructor in a list, without the explicit recursion in the sample below?

```
data Elem = A Int | B Char deriving Show

getA :: [Elem] -> Maybe Elem
getA [] = Nothing
getA (e:es) = 
    case e of 
        A a -> Just (A a)
        _   -> getA es
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simply

```
import Data.Maybe (listToMaybe)
getA xs = listToMaybe [e | e@(A _) <- xs]
```

Addendum: even better, future-proofed using an empty record pattern (kudos hammar):

```
getA xs = listToMaybe [e | e@(A{}) <- xs]
```

Note however, that this only works out so neatly for matching constructors. For general properties, `find` is nicer:

```
get prop xs = listToMaybe [e | e <- xs, prop e]
get prop xs = listToMaybe (filter prop xs)
get prop xs = find prop xs
```

Comment: I really like how this solution uses a list comprehension to workaround having to pattern match on more than just the desired data constructor. It can be improved using the empty record pattern used by @hammar in his answer.

Comment: @IonuțG.Stan agreed, that would future-proof it.

Answer (score 11):

You can use [`Data.List.find`](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-List.html#v%3afind).

```
getA = find isA
   where isA (A {}) = True
         isA _ = False
```

Comment: What's the `{}` part called? I've never seen it before in Haskell. I guess it matches 0 or many data constructor fields?

Comment: @IonuțG.Stan: It's a _record pattern_ with no field bindings. It just means that it doesn't matter how many fields the constructor has, so if you change it, you don't have to change this function.

Answer (score 3):

You could use find:

```
data Elem = A Int | B Char deriving Show
getA elements = find (\x->case x of (A _) -> True; _ -> False) elements
```

Comment: Thanks, very nice! Not the golf champion, though :-)!